# React Component code organization best practise

Tags: reactjs

Is it ok to have all the functions inside of the App.js in React and then passing them to the other components through context:

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        listName: '',
        existingListNames: [],

        item: {
            id: '',
            toDo: ''
        },
        listItems: []
    };

    this.onItemChange = this.onItemChange.bind(this);
    this.onItemAdd = this.onItemAdd.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/v1/names')
        .then(response => {
            const listItems = response.data;
            listItems.forEach(item => {
                this.setState({
                    existingListNames: [...this.state.existingListNames, item.name]
                })
            })
        })
}



onItemChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        item: {
            id: uuid(),
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    });
}

onItemAdd(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { item } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        listItems: [...this.state.listItems, item],
        item: {
            id: '',
            toDo: ''
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('formItem').reset();
}



render() {
    const currentItem = this.onItemChange;
    const addItem = this.onItemAdd;
    const { listItems, existingListNames, listName } = this.state;

    return (
        <div className="main-container">
            <Context.Provider
                value={{
                    currentItem,
                    addItem,
                    removeItem,
                    listItems,
                    existingListNames,
                    listName
                }}
            >
                <InputContainer />
            </Context.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

And then access them from the component:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Context from "../../../context/Context";

export default function ItemInput() {
    const { currentItem, addItem } = useContext(Context);

    return (
        <form className="item" id="formItem">
            <input
                onChange={currentItem}
                type="text"
                className="newInput"
                name="toDo"
                placeholder="New Task"
                autoComplete="off"
            />
            <button onClick={addItem} className="checkButton">
                <i className="fas fa-check fa-sm"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Or is it better to separate them into different files and import straigth into components instead. What if App.js gets really big with lots of functions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're looking for the "best practice" answer, since that's what you put in your title. That answer depends on your use case:

Propagating handlers to their respective children, should be done at the nearest parent to the child component. The only reason to use context would be if the parent-child relationship is not applicable to your Component hierarchy; i.e. one component to a random-component-nowhere-near-the-other.

Beyond one of those 2 scenarios, there's a lot of debate around the React community on using Context or Props for direct descendent children. To prepare yourself well for the eventual debate, feel free to [read up on the pros & cons of each](https://imranhsayed.medium.com/context-vs-props-in-react-197249408ea5) . If you do opt for context tho, there's some definite [disadvantages](https://blog.logrocket.com/pitfalls-of-overusing-react-context/).